# Automated webscraper for specific words

Tags: python

Let's say I want to make a website that automatically scrapes specific websites in order to find the ex. bike model that my customer has typed.

> **Customer:** Wants to find this one specific bike model that is really hard to get
>
> **Customer:** Finds the website [www.EXAMPLE.com](http://www.EXAMPLE.com), the website will notify him when there is an auction on ex. ebay or amazon.
>
> **Customer:** Creates free account, and makes a post.
>
> **Website:** Makes an automated scraping and keeps looking for this bike on ebay and amazon.
>
> **Website:** As soon as scraping succeed and finds the bike, website sends notification to the customer.

Is that possible to make in python? And will I be able to make such a website with little knowledge after learning a bit of Python?

Comment: Sure you can scrape other companies' catalogs for your own commercial use, it's generally a violation of their TOS, so noone here will help you with that. If you have a specific, on-topic programming question, that's what SO is for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it possible, you can achieve that by using a package such as [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for scraping and [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) to build the website, it does require however a bit of knowledge.

Feel free to post a question after diving into the two links

Comment: Well maybe i kinda wrote my post unclearly. 
Didnt mean like customer is gonna make a post on blog or forum, more like a window on main page where you put the model of the bike, and website starts automatically.

Something like this - https://imgur.com/a/65z3q90